# PDFBox - How to change encoding from WinAnsiEncoding to Unicode?

Tags: encoding, pdfbox, boxable

I am trying to find a way I could change the **WinAnsiEncoding** to **Unicode**, I've tried setting font like this,

```
PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
doc.addPage(page);

File unicodeFileLocation = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/lib/ARIALUNI.TTF"));
PDTrueTypeFont unicodeFont = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(doc, unicodeFileLocation);

...

// Create Table using boxable API
BaseTable table = new BaseTable(yStart, yStartNewPage, bottomMargin, tableWidth, margin, doc, page, true, drawContent);
// Title Field
Row<PDPage> titleRow = table.createRow(rowHeight);
Cell<PDPage> cell = titleRow.createCell(30, "Title");
cell = titleRow.createCell(70, TitleText);
cell.setFont(unicodeFont);

table.draw();
```

For simple Text this works fine, I can see the font change from Helvetica but if the text contains UTF-8 characters (e.g., U+0083 etc), I just see the following exception thrown,

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: U+0083 is not available in this font's encoding: WinAnsiEncoding
>       org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont.encode(PDTrueTypeFont.java:371)
>       org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.encode(PDFont.java:316)
>       org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.getStringWidth(PDFont.java:345)
>       be.quodlibet.boxable.text.PipelineLayer.push(PipelineLayer.java:65)
>       be.quodlibet.boxable.Paragraph.getLines(Paragraph.java:341)
>       be.quodlibet.boxable.Paragraph.getHeight(Paragraph.java:465)
>       be.quodlibet.boxable.Cell.getTextHeight(Cell.java:392)
>       be.quodlibet.boxable.Cell.getCellHeight(Cell.java:367)
>       be.quodlibet.boxable.Row.getHeight(Row.java:166)
>       be.quodlibet.boxable.Table.isEndOfPage(Table.java:728)
>       be.quodlibet.boxable.Table.drawRow(Table.java:224)
>       be.quodlibet.boxable.Table.draw(Table.java:200)
>       com.ssl.pew.controller.ExportPEW.processRequest(ExportPEW.java:498)
>       com.ssl.pew.controller.ExportPEW.doPost(ExportPEW.java:792)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

When I try to see the encoding type, it's always WinAnsiEncoding which I do not need.

```
Encoding encoding = unicodeFont.getEncoding();
String encodingName = encoding.getEncodingName();
```

This gives me WinAnsiEncoding, is there any way I could change this?

To me, it seems like it's because of WinAnsiEncoding and if somehow I could change that, I might be able to solve this issue.

It seems that mostly people decided to move to iText which is not an option for me.

Comment: Use `PDType0Font.load()` instead. I'm pretty sure I answered that one, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @TilmanHausherr - Actually figured out that I was using 2.0.4 version, updated that to the latest stable build of 2.0.7 and now it's picking encodingType of the font that I'm using.

Comment: I wonder if I understood the question at all now... the problem I thought you were having would also occur with 2.0.7. With `PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF` you'll get only 255 characters maximum, with `PDType0Font.load()` you get all (see also FAQ).

Answer (score 1):

The [FAQ](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html) says:

> Font Handling
>
> I’m getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: … is not available in this font’s encoding: WinAnsiEncoding
>
> Check whether the character is available in WinAnsiEncoding by looking at the PDF Specification Appendix D. If not, but if it is available in this font (in windows, have a look with charmap.exe), then load the font with PDType0Font.load(), see also in the EmbeddedFonts.java example in the source code download.

It's working for me with, for example,

```
PDType0Font.load(document, new ClassPathResource("fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf").getFile());
```

Answer (score -2):

Here try this

```
PDFont font = PDTrueTypeFont.load(document, new File(fontPath)), WinAnsiEncoding.INSTANCE);
```

Comment: WinAnsiEncoding is the default so this won't help.